# Codeigniter getinstance() error not loading any library,helpers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i m creating a login system in codeigniter. i m new in codeigniter. i have getting this error when testing my login system

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 92

Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object in P:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\xxxxx\application\controllers\login.php on line 92
```

here is my login.php controller file

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        if($this->is_logged_in() === true){
            redirect('welcome');
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $data['class_name'] = get_class();
        $data['no_header'] = '1';
        $data['no_footer'] = '1';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $query = $this->admin_model->validate();
        print_r($query);
        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'AdminID' => $query,
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('welcome');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            echo "here";
            exit;
            $this->index();
        }
    }   

    function signup()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'signup_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }

    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $CI =&get_instance();
        $is_logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in === true)
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried

```
$CI =&get_instance();

$CI =get_instance();

$this->session->userdata
```

all three way but getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling the `is_logged_in()` function in the Controller's constructor without calling the parent constructor first. maybe that's probably why some resources aren't loaded yet.

try adding this:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); //you always have to call parent's constructor before ANYTHING

    if($this->is_logged_in() === true){
        redirect('welcome');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading the session library for the **new** instance you create with get_instance().

Simply do, assuming session is already loaded and, as noted by @jere, you call the parent::__construct() in your controller:

```
function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if(isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in === true)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't know why using another instance of the class here.

If you oughta do that, try loading the session library again, like:

```
$CI->load->library('session')
$is_logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
//rest of your old code
```